# Does Lua __gc metamethod now work for table (Lua 5.2.1) ?

Tags: garbage-collection, lua, destructor, metatable

I've been a little surprised, because I have read before, that `__gc` metamethod is only called for userdata and never for tables. ([LuaFAQ : Why don't the __gc and __len metamethods work on tables?](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaFaq))

But, recently, I have tried it and found it actually works! Try this code with Lua 5.2.1:

```
do
  local b = setmetatable({a = 1}, {__gc = function(self) print(self.a); end});
end
collectgarbage();
```

But I can't find anywhere the changelog for this, so I'm little frustrated and afraid to use it.

Maybe, someone can prove my suggestion? Or it is an undocumented behaviour?
As for me it will be nice to have a regular way to create table destructor, and I will be glad if my observation is right.

Comment: http://www.lua.org/versions.html#5.2 - "Lua 5.2 was released on 16 Dec 2011. Its main new features are [...] finalizers for tables."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html) section [2.5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.5.1) indicates that tables do support the `__gc` metamethod. Specifically, it says

> For an object (table or userdata) to be finalized when collected, you must mark it for finalization. You mark an object for finalization when you set its metatable and the metatable has a field indexed by the string "__gc".

The similar documentation in the [5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.10.1) says

> Using the C API, you can set garbage-collector metamethods for userdata

It seems pretty clear that Lua 5.2 now explicitly supports the `__gc` metamethod for tables.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I should carefully read reference. Where was my eyes. Sorry for stupid question.